# BuildPack Unable to resolve artifact for gradle multiproject java springboot code

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, buildpack, multi-project

I created a settings file which has
a rootProject.name followed by include statements for each microservice.
But during build with the buildpack I get

```
! failed with status code: 145
[builder] unable to invoke layer creator
                                                                                                     │ [builder] unable to contribute application layer
│ [builder] unable to resolve artifact
│ [builder] unable to find single built artifact in build/libs/*.[jw]ar, candidate
│ s: []. If this is unexpected, please try setting rootProject.name in settings.gr
│ adle or add a project.toml file and exclude the build/ directory. For details se
│ e https://buildpacks.io/docs/app-developer-guide/using-project-descriptor/.
```

So I created a project.toml file in root folder and repeated build.

```
[build]
exclude = [
    "/README.md",
    "bash-script-buildpack"
    "issues"
    "infra"
    "docs"
    "docker-compose"
    "externalAuthServer"
    "important-sites.md"
    "build\."
]

include = [
    "microservice-a"
    "microservice-b"
    "microservice-c"
    "ui-app"
]
```

Observed the same error as above.

Not sure what I am exactly missing!

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the command you ran?

Comment: The error is telling you that after building, the buildpack can't find any output files. See how the list of candidates in the error message is empty: `candidates: []`. The buildpack looks in `build/libs` for any files ending in `.jar` or `.war` by default, so it's not seeing any of those. Are you expecting a JAR or WAR to exist there? When you `gradle assemble` locally, what do you end up within the `build/libs/` directory?

Comment: I have been able to resolve the issue by updating my waypoint.hcl file and defining exactly for each app for the build stanza the environment properties BP_GRADLE_BUILT_MODULE and BP_GRADLE_BUILT_ARTIFACT for the artifact build jar location.